# MATLAB camera calibration coordinate system

Tags: matlab, camera, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

Does anyone know about the MATLAB camera calibrator coordinate system? Whether it is right handed or left handed? what are the x, y, z positive directions? please tell me some tips and guide about an accurate hand-eye calibration.

Comment: "Left handed". The cross product of x and y is z.

Comment: Doesnt that mean the coordinate system is right turning? Which would make sense, since that's the usual way in mathematics

Comment: x ^ y = z is a RHS. I can't confirm this is the camera calibrator coordinate system, but I'd be willing to bet...

Answer (score 1):

The coordinate systems are right-handed. See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/gs/coordinate-systems.html?refresh=true) for details.